# strange behaviour with glossaries see key

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries

I have been baffled by exactly how to use the `see` key of the `glossaries` package.

Section 8 of the manual writes:

> Note that in this case, the entry with the see key will automatically
>   be added to the glossary, but the cross-referenced entry won’t.

Contrary to what the manual says, specifying a `see` key does not add the automatically add the entry to the glossaries as my MWE shows. I got one of the entry to show up by using `\glssee` within the `description` key, but it fails to generate the text `see also`. I can manually write the cross-reference within the `description` key, but I am curious as to why the `see` key doesn't seem to do what the manual says. What gives?

```
\usepackage[notree,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Blackbox}
{
  name=Blackbox models,
  sort=blackbox,
  description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{blackbox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques, without knowledge of physical inner workings of the system, resulting in an \emph{empirical} model}
}
\newglossaryentry{Whitebox}
{
  name=Whitebox models,
  sort=whitebox,
  description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{whitebox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through first principles, laws of physics and explicit assumed relationships between the input and output through prior knowledge of the system, resulting in a \emph{mechanistic} model}
}
\newglossaryentry{Mechanistic}
{
  name=Mechanistic models,
  sort=mechanistic,
  description={},
  see=[see also]{Whitebox},
  nonumberlist
}
\newglossaryentry{Empirical}
{
  name=Empirical models,
  sort=empirical,
  description={\glssee[see also]{Empirical}{Blackbox}},
  see=[see also]{Blackbox},
  nonumberlist
}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
Something about \gls{Blackbox} and \gls{Whitebox}
\newpage
\printglossary[title={Glossaries}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To make a cross-referencing item appear even without citing it, it needs a chance to be written to the glossary, so put `\makeglossaries` before the entry definition.
2. The `\glssee` is to be used outside of the actual definitions. The following works:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[notree,shortcuts]{glossaries}
   \makeglossaries         %% Put that here, so entries can be written to the glossary

   \newglossaryentry{Blackbox}
   {
     name=Blackbox models,
     sort=blackbox,
     description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{blackbox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques, without knowledge of physical inner workings of the system, resulting in an \emph{empirical} model}
   }
   \newglossaryentry{Empirical}
   {
     name=Empirical models,
     sort=empirical,
     description={Empirical descr},
     see=[see also]{Blackbox},
     nonumberlist
   }

   %\glssee[see also]{Empirical}{Blackbox} %% We need that to include Empirical when just citing Blackbox; or use the 'see' key in Empirical; put it after \makeglossaries and the entry definitions

   \begin{document}

   Something about \gls{Blackbox}


   \newpage
   \printglossary[title={Glossaries}]
   \end{document}
   ```

   In this case, both Empirical and Blackbox show up. Alternatively, use the `\glssee` instead of the `see` key in Empirical.

Comment: Sorry I don't see how I read it wrong: "Note that in this case, the entry with the see key will automatically be added to the glossary, but the cross-referenced entry won’t"  In my case, the entry *with* the see key is Empirical, the cross-referenced entry is blackbox. The former, as the wording suggest, should be added to the glossaries automatically. If I did not cite `\gls{blackbox}`, then the wording would suggest blackbox won't be added to the glossaries, since blackbox is the *cross-referenced* entry. This I haven't tried

Comment: Are you suggeesting "see" key does not function when `nonumberlist` is used? I thought it would print the description for Empirical as "See also blackbox" and give a hyperlink (if hyperref is loaded) to the glossary entry of blackbox. In another words, where is the see also text and how to bring it up?

Comment: @MobiusPizza I misread your problem, and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. When I compiled your answer, I still don't see any automatically added text of "see also"? Do I have to add it manually to description of Empirical? If so, what is the point of the optional argument `[see also]`?

Comment: @MobiusPizza To see the "see also" part in Empirical, the Empirical entry needs `nonumberlist=false`, or just no entry of `nonumberlist`. Then you get a reference to Blackbox, even hyperlinked when using `hyperref`.